# jqgrid subgrid primary key

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, primary-key, subgrid

I have a question about how the subgrid links data.

I have two databases. One for subgrid and one for maingrid info.

For simplicity, both are like:

```
id Serial
1 1
2 2
3 40
```

As you can see the PrimaryKey which is id, is usually the same as Serial. But not always. This means that if I add a new entry to the subgrid database, with id of any # but serial of 40, it will link to the maingrid database id of 40, instead of Serial of 40.

How do I tell the subgrid (or the maingrid) to link via the Serial column and not the PrimaryKey (id) column>?

In my subgrid php i have

```
SELECT id, Serial FROM subgrid WHERE Serial = ?
```

My maingrid php only has
Code:

```
$grid->setSubGridGrid("sub.php");
```

Surely there are options to set what the linked column is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here:

http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=12661&#post12661

fillllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll